# get value and pass it to another activity from xml

Tags: android

I'm using the CustomizedList View code from this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

and I modified it by adding YouTube Videos Id's , but I have a problem when I click on list item and I want to start new activity to play Video , I don't know how to pass the video ID to the next Activity !

My problem is how to get the value of KEY_VID_ID in CustomizedListView Activity !!!

CuztomizedListView.java Code

```
public class CustomizedListView extends Activity {
// All static variables
static final String URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/music/music.xml";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_SONG = "song"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";
static final String KEY_VID_ID = "vid_id";


ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
    // looping through all song nodes <song>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
        map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
        map.put(KEY_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTIST));
        map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
        map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));
        map.put(KEY_VID_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_VID_ID));

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        songsList.add(map);
    }


    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);        
    list.setAdapter(adapter);


    // Click event for single list row
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(CustomizedListView.this, PlayVideo.class);

        //  intent.setData(Uri.parse());
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });     
}   
}
```

LazyAdapter

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
    TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.artist); // artist name
    TextView duration = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.duration); // duration
    ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image

    HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
    song = data.get(position);

    // Setting all values in listview
    title.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_TITLE));
    artist.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_ARTIST));
    duration.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DURATION));
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_THUMB_URL), thumb_image);
    return vi;
}
}
```

PlayVideo.java

```
public class PlayVideo extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

static private final String DEVELOPER_KEY = "AIzaSyBOQlVNfn6TY_TpyWYKMbwNPk09AhBRWXw";
 static private final String VIDEO = "oZbeL1ciR4E";
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.playvideo);
          YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView)
findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
       youTubeView.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
     Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
       if (extras != null) {
      String VIDEOs = extras.getString("videourl");
      TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_text);
      text.setText(VIDEOs);
       }

      }
     @Override
     public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider,
YouTubeInitializationResult error) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Oh no! "+error.toString(),
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
   @Override
   public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
boolean wasRestored) {
     /*  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
       if (extras != null) {
      String VIDEOs = extras.getString("videourl");
      TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_text);
      text.setText(VIDEOs);*/

          player.loadVideo(VIDEO);
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CustomizedListView.this, PlayVideo.class);
intent.putExtra("ID",KEY_ID);
startActivity(intent);
```

and get it in PlayVideo.java like this

```
String Key_id = getIntent().getExtras().getString("ID");
```

now you have one query that how to get ID from list. then i would suggest that give your view that is in custom adapter class a tag which is your ID of video so that when you click on list it will give you clicked view where you can get tag of view so ultimately you will get ID of video. so that you can pass that video tag to another activity. just like this:

```
vi.setTag(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_ID));
```

in lazy loader class in getView() method. and then get tag in click event of list like this:

```
String tag = view.getTag().toString();
```

Hope it Helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code into your   onItemClick method

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CustomizedListView.this, PlayVideo.class);        
intent.putExtra("videoId", id);
startActivity(intent );
```

Comment: I know how to pass the string to the next Activity , but my problem is how to get the value that saved on XML file ??

Comment: I am  not clear what you told. Do u want to get the value that u pass into intent

Comment: I have in my XML file Vid_id value and other values , I parse it and show all values as a list, you can check LazyAdapter code above, what I need now to get back value of Vid_id from list I've parsed then send it to PlayVideo activity , the problem that I'm facing that I can't get the Value of Vid_id that saved on my XML file in CustomizedListView Activity.
did you check the tutorial code that I'm using?

Comment: post your PlayVideo activity class

Comment: I added it to the question , I tried to pass Key_duration as
    intent.putExtra("videourl",KEY_DURATION);
and tried to show it as a textview on playvideo activity , I got value "duration" on the textview

Comment: you want to send list  from your activity

Comment: you want to get extra value into PlayVideo  class but you did not send any value from CustomizedListView .

Answer (score 0):

A good way to get ID of the videos from XML is adding the tag attribute into your items ( `android:tag="v=ID"` ). So, modify the ItemClickListener to:

```
 // Click event for single list row
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(CustomizedListView.this, PlayVideo.class);
        //Verify if we have the ID and then send to another activity.
        if(view.getTag() != null)
                 intent.putExtra("id", "" + view.getTag());
        //  intent.setData(Uri.parse());
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });
```

And then, in you PlayVideo.class, in onCreate method you can have the Id doing:

```
String id = null;
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras()
if(extras != null && extras.containsKey("id"))
    id = extras.getString("id");
```

Now the string id will contain the id you want.

Answer (score 0):

**In first Activity**

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this);   
i.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", strName);
i.startActivity();
```

**In second activity**

```
Intent n = getIntent();
String newString= extras.getString("STRING_I_NEED");
```

Comment: I know how to pass the string to the next Activity , but my problem is how to get the value that saved on XML file ??

Comment: collect it into an array and use the same put-extra Technic.

Comment: I already used LazyAdapter but I don't know how to get values in CuztomizedListview activity , I posted lazyadapter on my question

Comment: do u want to get list in your Lazy adapter

Answer (score 0):

put this code at your CustomizedListView class

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CustomizedListView.this, PlayVideo.class);
                        truckIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        truckIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        truckIntent.putExtra(KEY_VID_ID, ID);

                        startActivity(intent);
```

put following code at your playvideo.class

```
String Key_id = getIntent().getExtras().getString("ID");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what are you asking. I have the same problem. You can make the value in a string like this for example: String url = getItem(pos).getLink(); 
I received the position and link and i made a string.

Here is my code example:

```
viewHolder.btnDownload = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btnDownload);
viewHolder.btnDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //getItemId(pos);
                String url = getItem(position).getLink();
```